# Cannot select text in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have an UITextView. Then I've added double tap gesture recognizer to the UITextView. Therefore I can't select text in UITextView when i double tap in UITextView.
How i can select text and get double tap event at the same time?
Thank in advance

This is my code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(respondToTapGesture:)];
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [textMeaning addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
```

Comment: try setting the gesture recognizer attribute cancelsTouchesInView to false.

Comment: @thinhvd uncheck selectable property of UITextView from interce Builder. and set it to true after double tap gesture. try it it will work.

Comment: I create UITextView by code. I set selectable property to YES, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
   [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
   [_txtVw addGestureRecognizer:tap];


}

-(void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
 { 

      UITextView *textView_New = (UITextView *)recognizer.view;
      CGPoint pos = [recognizer locationInView:textView_New];

      NSLog(@"Tap Gesture Coordinates: %.2f %.2f", pos.x, pos.y);

      UITextPosition *tapPos = [textView_New closestPositionToPoint:pos];

      UITextRange * word = [textView_New.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPos withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
     NSLog(@"WORD: %@", [textView_New textInRange:word]);

 }
```

Comment: It will select all text in UITextView. I just want to select a word in UITextView

Comment: yes.. here i am selecting all the text of textview. So you want to select the word on which you have tapped right??

Comment: @user4261201 how to add text in textview.i have disabled scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If you add gesture -> event select is not availible

So, you should change your flow!

Comment: I don't set select event. The iOS select text automatically when i double click in text in UITextView.

Comment: You disable select/edit uitextview, try this:
textView.selectable = NO;
// Or
textView.editable = NO;

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your present code:

**.h file**

```
UITextField *txtField;
```

**.m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [txtField addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
    // Perform your operation which you want to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [txtField addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {

  [self.titleField setSelectedTextRange:[self.titleField textRangeFromPosition:self.titleField.beginningOfDocument toPosition:self.titleField.endOfDocument]];

    }
}
```

try this

to select text within a range

```
int start = 2;
int end = 5;
UITextPosition *startPosition = [self positionFromPosition:self.beginningOfDocument offset:start];
UITextPosition *endPosition = [self positionFromPosition:self.beginningOfDocument offset:end];
UITextRange *selection = [self textRangeFromPosition:startPosition toPosition:endPosition];
self.selectedTextRange = selection;
```

Comment: It will select all text in UITextView. I just want to select a word in UITextView

Answer (score 0):

I don't want the user to be able to alter the text, so deselected "Editable" in interface builder for the UITextView.
Set the delegate for the UITextView to this class !!!

Then use

```
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
[textView setSelectedTextRange:[textView textRangeFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:textView.endOfDocument]]; }
```